# Is it possible to set order by some field by default?

Tags: c#, .net-core, sql-order-by, default

When I get a collection of objects from dbContext, is it possible to set an order-by, by default?

For example, say I have a collection of Customers. Inside my controller I can simply do: `_context.Customers.Where(.....)`, return a list.

However, I might have multiple calls to `_context.Customers.Where(.....)` and I don't want to add Order-by to every instance. Instead I want order-by to happen on retrieving the data automatically.

I'm running .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: You could create a stored procedure for this which takes the `Where` arguments as parameters. Instead of querying your data via linqs `Where` you would call the stored procedure. But this depends on the complexity of your `Where` clauses.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, would explain why I couldn't find any information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, not possible since it's a explicit operation. Same as in SQL, where you will have to apply `order by` clause in order to get ordered data otherwise no order is guaranteed.

So in your case you will have to apply `OrderBy()` explicitly saying `_context.Customers.Where(.....).OrderBy(...)`. Though you can pull this operation into a method probably to make it reusable